Angular ng-content inside *ngIf="false" triggers OnInit's child?
With angular (17 or 18)
<ng-content> must not be rendered inside an *ngIf="false"
But content child OnInit is triggered !?
For test, I tried :
<div class="content" *ngIf="false">
   <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>

And :
<app-parent>
    <app-child></app-child>
</app-parent>

And for app-child :
ngOnInit() {
    alert('OnInit done...');
}

Then alert is triggered, and it proves that ngOnInit is initialized even if it is not rendered because of *ngIf="false" !!?
Tested on Angular 17 and 18 on stackblitz :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-2tjcvw?file=src%2Fmain.ts
What do I not understand? What am I doing wrong? Is there a fix?
Or, should I report a bug to Angular team?

Although you are passing the component inside the parent. The component is still intialized using the grandparent component. Meaning, I am able to pass @Input and @Output from the child and the grandparent. Because the component gets initialized in respect to the grand parent scope. It will just be projected/moved into the parent's ng-content but the initialization lies on the grandparent so ngOnInit and other hooks must execute. This is my understanding so it is not a bug.
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
      <h2>Parent Component</h2>
      <div class="content" *ngIf="false">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
      </div>
  `,
})
export class ParentComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h3>Child Component</h3>
    <button (click)="outputEmitter.emit()">emit</button>
  `,
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() input: any;
  @Output() outputEmitter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  ngOnInit() {
    alert('OnInit done...' + this.input);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ParentComponent, ChildComponent],
  template: `
    <app-parent>
      <app-child [input]="name" (outputEmitter)="emit()"></app-child>
    </app-parent>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  emit() {
    alert('emit from child to grandparent');
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Ok, I understand. Thanks for your answer. Unfortunatly, I'll manage *ngIf from grand-parent even if it's not the niciest way. Strange thing is that when *ngIf is false, child component totally disapear from DOM. It's like if in this nested way, it only affects visibility.

@HubertBlein From a compiler perspective its difficult to understand that the component will never be rendered. Since this is an impossible scenario, why would anyone hide the ng-content when it can just be removed from HTML.

Sure, ngIf was always false for test purpose. But in my use case, I wanted to use parent container to embed a reusable logic to determine wether to display the content or not. If true, content needed to be wrapped with intermediate html props and events.

@HubertBlein Think for compiler perspective, its cannot determine whether to hide or show since its a conditional, so it initializes
